# R code for downloading all the pdfs given on a site: Web scraping

Tags: html, r, json, url, web-scraping

I want to code in R which can download all the pdfs given on this URL: https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/AnnualPublications.aspx?head=Handbook%20of%20Statistics%20on%20Indian%20Economy
and then download all the pdfs in a folder. I tried the following code with the help of https://towardsdatascience.com but the code is erroring out as

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
page <- read_html("https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/AnnualPublications.aspx? 
head=Handbook%20of%20Statistics%20on%20Indian%20Economy") %>%

raw_list <- page %>% # takes the page above for which we've read the html
html_nodes("a") %>%  # find all links in the page
html_attr("href") %>% # get the url for these links
str_subset("\\.pdf") %>% # find those that end in pdf only
str_c("https://rbi.org.in", .) %>% # prepend the website to the url
map(read_html) %>% # take previously generated list of urls and read them
map(html_node, "#raw-url") %>% # parse out the 'raw' url - the link for the download button
map(html_attr, "href") %>% # return the set of raw urls for the download buttons
str_c("https://www.rbi.org.in", .) %>% # prepend the website again to get a full url
for (url in raw_list)
{ download.file(url, destfile = basename(url), mode = "wb") 
}
```

I am not able to interpret why is the code erroring out. If someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to run your code, I ran into "Verify that you are a human" and "Please ensure that your browser has Javascript enabled" dialogues. This suggests that you cannot open the page using Rvest but you need to use [RSelenium browser automation](http://joshuamccrain.com/tutorials/web_scraping_R_selenium.html) instead.

Here is a modified version using RSelenium

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(rvest)

library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/AnnualPublications.aspx?head=Handbook%20of%20Statistics%20on%20Indian%20Economy")
page <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
read_html(page) -> html

html %>%
html_nodes("a") %>%  
html_attr("href") %>% 
str_subset("\\.PDF") -> urls
urls %>% str_split(.,'/') %>% unlist() %>% str_subset("\\.PDF") -> filenames

for(u in 1:length(urls)) {
  cat(paste('downloading: ', u, ' of ', length(urls), '\n'))
  download.file(urls[u], filenames[u], mode='wb')
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: Re: file names -- you change `filenames` to e.g.  `paste0('pdf',seq(1, length(urls),1),'.pdf') -> filenames`

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi. I just had one more query. So on right hand column you can see data for various years are given ex: 2020, 2019 etc. Can we modify the code somehow so that this code can download data for that years as well.

Comment: @Manu - I believe you could use `elem<- remDr$findElement(using="link text", "2020)` and `elem$clickElement()` but I haven't tested this solution. I would recommend asking a new question.

Comment: Hi.Thank you. The web page of 2020 year is opening (as in getting accessed for 2020) but somehow the files are not downloading in system. Yes will ask this as a new question. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

there were small mistakes. the Website uses capital letters for PDF endings, and you don't need to use `str_c("https://rbi.org.in", .)`. Finally, I think using purrr's walk2 functions is smoother (as it was probably in the original code).

I haven't executed the code, cos I don't need so many pdfs, so, report if it works.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
page <- read_html("https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/AnnualPublications.aspx?head=Handbook%20of%20Statistics%20on%20Indian%20Economy")
  
  raw_list <- page %>% # takes the page above for which we've read the html
  html_nodes("a") %>%  # find all links in the page
  html_attr("href") %>% # get the url for these links
  str_subset("\\.PDF") %>% 
  walk2(., basename(.), download.file, mode = "wb")
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. The code worked perfectly. I had just one more doubt. How do I change code if I want pdfs to be named as pdf1, pdf2 and so on instead of default names